# How can I get a fullscreen with libvlc android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, libvlc

I'm trying to display an udp stream from a GoPro camera, but when I do it that way :

```
ArrayList<String> _Options = new ArrayList<String>();
_Options.add("--file-caching=2000");
_Options.add("--network-caching=150");
_Options.add("--clock-jitter=0");
_Options.add("--live-caching=1000");
_Options.add("--clock-synchro=0");
_Options.add("--fullscreen");
_Options.add("-vvv");
_Options.add("--drop-late-frames");
_Options.add("--skip-frames");
_myLibVlc = new LibVLC(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getContext(), _Options);
_myPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_myLibVlc);
_myPlayer.setAspectRatio("16:9");
_myPlayer.setScale(1);
_myVout = _myPlayer.getVLCVout();
_myVout.setVideoView(_myVideoView);
_myVout.attachViews();
```

But I only get an tiny video like that :

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOzpo.jpg)

I tried using DisplayMetrics but it crashes when I use vout.setWindowSize()

ps : I'm sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: why not resize `_myVideoView`?

Comment: Don't worry, I found the solution, just needed to change it to VLCVideoLayout and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Kanoto, can you please show your code as i also want to play video, but not able to play it..